# Android Studio github library implementation

Tags: java, android, github

I want to use this library in my project https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View
but after I follow provided instructions I still can't get it to work.

I added new entry in build.gradle(: app)

```
dependencies {
   ...
    compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'

}
```

I got tons of errors e.g., import errors inside provided classes or depricated methods, file acces denied, and many more.

Could somebody introduce me as I'm fresh into importing from github?
[image]

Comment: That is a very old library and has not been updated in years it looks like. It could very well be that it has compatibility issues now. You can also see there is an open issue for this https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/issues/541

Answer (score 0):

There are many alternatives for this library you can use this one

**1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:**

```
allprojects {repositories {  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }}}
```

**2. Add the dependency**

```
dependencies {compile 'com.github.tobiasschuerg:android-week-view:-SNAPSHOT'}
```

For full project visit this [Github Code](https://www.gorute.com/wc3sa)

Comment: It is for android applications and i am not sure about java app